# Merging two dictionaries by key in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm looking for help in merging two dictionaries in a specific way.
I would be very grateful for any thoughts.

I have two dictionaries like this:
1st dict:

```
servers:
  server1:
    Property1: A
    Property2: B
    Property3: C
  server2:
    Property1: A
    Property2: B
    Property3: C
```

2nd dict:

```
management:
  server1: ip1_addr
  server2: ip2_addr
```

Desired result:

```
servers:
  server1:
    Property1: A
    Property2: B
    Property3: C
    Property4: ip1_addr
  server2:
    Property1: A
    Property2: B
    Property3: C
    Property4: ip2_addr
```

Or I may have chosen the wrong path, all I need is to loop over two that dictionaries in one go, to get ip1_addr under server1 key and ip2_addr under server2 key

Answer (score 5):

There are more options:

1. Convert the dictionary *management*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        mgmt: "{{ mgmt|d({})|
                  combine({item.key: {'Property4': item.value}}) }}"
      loop: "{{ management|dict2items }}"
```

---

If you want to avoid iteration use:

a) the filter [*community.general.dict_kv*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries)

```yaml
    mgmt: "{{ dict(management.keys()|
                   zip(management.values()|
                       map('community.general.dict_kv', 'Property4'))) }}"
```

b) the filter [*community.general.json_query*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_selecting_json_data.html)

```yaml
    mgmt: "{{ dict(management|dict2items|
                   json_query('[].[key, {Property4: value}]')) }}"
```

c) [*Jinja*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#)

```yaml
    mgmt_str: |
      {% for k,v in management.items() %}
      {{ k }}:
        Property4: {{ v }}
      {% endfor %}
    mgmt: "{{ mgmt_str|from_yaml }}"
```

---

All options give the same result

```yaml
  mgmt:
    server1:
      Property4: ip1_addr
    server2:
      Property4: ip2_addr
```

Then, [*combine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) the dictionaries

```yaml
  srvs: "{{ servers|combine(mgmt, recursive=True) }}"
```

gives the desired result

```yaml
  srvs:
    server1:
      Property1: A
      Property2: B
      Property3: C
      Property4: ip1_addr
    server2:
      Property1: A
      Property2: B
      Property3: C
      Property4: ip2_addr
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    servers:
      server1:
        Property1: A
        Property2: B
        Property3: C
      server2:
        Property1: A
        Property2: B
        Property3: C
        
    management:
      server1: ip1_addr
      server2: ip2_addr

    mgmt: "{{ dict(management.keys()|
                   zip(management.values()|
                       map('community.general.dict_kv', 'Property4'))) }}"
    srvs: "{{ servers|combine(mgmt, recursive=True) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: mgmt
    - debug:
        var: srvs
```

---

2. Use Jinja to create the YAML structure and convert it using the filter *from_yaml*. The declaration of *srvs* below gives the same result

```yaml
    srvs_str: |
      {% for k,v in servers.items() %}
      {{ k }}:
         {{ v|combine({'Property4': management[k]}) }}
      {% endfor %}
    srvs: "{{ srvs_str|from_yaml }}"
```

---

3. If you want to iterate the result it's easier to convert both dictionaries to lists

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        mgmt_list: "{{ mgmt_list|d([]) +
                       [{'server': item.key, 'Property4': item.value}] }}"
      loop: "{{ management|dict2items }}"

    - set_fact:
        srvs_list: "{{ srvs_list|d([]) +
                       [{'server': item.key}|combine(item.value)] }}"
      loop: "{{ servers|dict2items }}"
```

---

If you want to avoid iteration use *json_query*

```yaml
    mgmt_list: "{{ management|dict2items(key_name='server',
                                         value_name='Property4') }}"
    srvs_list: "{{ servers|dict2items|
                   json_query('[].merge({server: key}, value)') }}"
```

---

give

```yaml
  mgmt_list:
  - Property4: ip1_addr
    server: server1
  - Property4: ip2_addr
    server: server2

  srvs_list:
  - Property1: A
    Property2: B
    Property3: C
    server: server1
  - Property1: A
    Property2: B
    Property3: C
    server: server2
```

Then use [Community.General](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/index.html#community-general) filter [*community.general.lists_mergeby*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_merging_lists_of_dictionaries.html#merging-lists-of-dictionaries)

```yaml
  srvs: "{{ srvs_list|community.general.lists_mergeby(mgmt_list, 'server') }}"
```

gives a list, instead of the expected dictionary

```yaml
  srvs:
  - Property1: A
    Property2: B
    Property3: C
    Property4: ip1_addr
    server: server1
  - Property1: A
    Property2: B
    Property3: C
    Property4: ip2_addr
    server: server2
```

You can convert the list to the dictionary

```yaml
  srvs_dict: "{{ dict(srvs|map(attribute='server')|zip(srvs)) }}"
```

, or

```yaml
  srvs_dict: "{{ dict(srvs|json_query('[].[server, @]')) }}"
```

Both options give the same result

```yaml
  srvs_dict:
    server1:
      Property1: A
      Property2: B
      Property3: C
      Property4: ip1_addr
      server: server1
    server2:
      Property1: A
      Property2: B
      Property3: C
      Property4: ip2_addr
      server: server2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    servers:
      server1:
        Property1: A
        Property2: B
        Property3: C
      server2:
        Property1: A
        Property2: B
        Property3: C
        
    management:
      server1: ip1_addr
      server2: ip2_addr

    mgmt_list: "{{ management|dict2items(key_name='server',
                                         value_name='Property4') }}"
    srvs_list: "{{ servers|dict2items|
                   json_query('[].merge({server: key}, value)') }}"
    srvs: "{{ srvs_list|community.general.lists_mergeby(mgmt_list, 'server') }}"
    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: mgmt_list
    - debug:
        var: srvs_list
    - debug:
        var: srvs
```

---